# Как вставить внешнее изображение в MovieClip Flash, заменив им текущее

Tags: flash, actionscript

Как вставить внешнее изображение в MovieClip Flash, заменив им текущее. Имеется Flash с несколькими MovieClip, необходимо загружать в них различные изображения из внешних файлов.
Выполняю загрузку во Flash так - загрузка проходит успешно.
        var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest("im.png"));
Вопрос: как загруженное изображение загрузить в определенный MovieClip, заменив им текущее изображение MovieClip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все так как вы описали, то относительно легко:

```
mc.removeChild(img); // удаляем старый имаж
mc.addChild(imgLoader); // добавляем новый
```

где:
mc - ссылка на экземпляр MovieClip

img - старое изображение

imgLoader - уже загруженный имаж

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я представлял что как-то так делается, но различные варинты не работали. Но у меня тогда дополнительный вопрос:
Как обратиться к старой картинке? Она у меня присутствует в библиотеке под названием: im.png и на основе нее создан MovieClip.

Comment: Как задать переменную img - которая отвечает за старую картинку?

Comment: К сожалению не особо силен в Flash CS Pro, не буду гадать.
Могу предложить добавлять "старую" картинку при старте флешки, и затем удалять её, доступ к ней будет проще. Еще есть вариант - добавить все картинки сразу, и менять свойство visible, то есть ставить visible = true, той которую нужно показать, visible = false соответственно остальным. Но лучший вариант, это загрузка/выгрузка, память экономится, плюс имажи можно динамически менять без перезагрузки всей флешки.

Comment: Так вот у меня вопрос как все это сделать из программного кода, как добавлять картинку - как к ней вообще обратиться? Я не знаю как мне добраться до картинки MovieClip из программного кода, вы написали: 
mc.removeChild(img); // удаляем старый имаж
так вот у меня и вопрос, как обратиться к ней - по имени файла, создать какую-то переменную определенного типа? Смысл загрузки - выгрузки мне был изначально понятен, а как это в программном коде прописать?

Comment: У меня есть еще второй вариант как я могу это сделать: но для него мне нужно программно задать точку регистрации MovieClip. Если бы мне подсказали как это сделать - я бы смог воспользоваться этим вариантом.

Comment: Вот переменная/экземпляр (img) внутри класса указывающая на загруженный имаж.

    private var url:String = "Image.gif";
    private var img:Loader = new Loader();
    public function LoaderExample() {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            img.load(request);
            addChild(img);
    }
Если грузите несколько имажей, значит нужен будет массив или именование экземпляров.


Задание точки регистрации.

    public function setRegistrationPoint(s:Sprite, regx:Number,regy:Number )
    {
        s.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -regx, -regy);
    }